# Cómo hago para poder usar un item o elemento de una lista en otra lista?

Tags: c#, mvc, lista

este es el Código de la clase:

```
public class MSequence
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Comments { get; set; }
    public MSquenceType MSType { get; set; }
    public List<MItem> Items { get; set; }

    public MSequence()
    {

    }
}

public class MSquenceType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class MItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Comments { get; set; }
    public int Duration { get; set; }
    public int Priority { get; set; }
    public MItemType MIType { get; set; }
    public string File { get; set; }
}

public enum MItemType { Video, Sound, Image }
```

Esta es la lista donde creo9 el item que quiero utilizar en la otra lista

```
var item = new System.Collections.Generic.List<MItem>
{
    new MItem()
    {
        Id  = 4,
        Name = "El Triple",
        Description = "Desc1",
        MIType = MItemType.Video,
        Duration = 5,
        Priority = 2
    },
    new MItem()
    {
        Id  = 15,
        Name = "1 año Gratis",
        Description = "Desc1",
        MIType = MItemType.Video,
        Duration = 5,
        Priority = 2
    },
    new MItem()
    {
        Id  = 3,
        Name = "El Triple",
        Description = "Desc1",
        MIType = MItemType.Video,
        Duration = 5,
        Priority = 2
    },
    new MItem()
    {
        Id  = 2,
        Name = "Verano conecta'o",
        Description = "Desc1",
        MIType = MItemType.Video,
        Duration = 5,
        Priority = 2
    },
    new MItem()
    {
        Id  = 1,
        Name = "Llama y llama",
        Description = "Desc1",
        MIType = MItemType.Video,
        Duration = 5,
        Priority = 2
    },

    new MItem()
    {
        Id  = 6,
        Name = "Internet sin límites",
        Description = "Desc1",
        MIType = MItemType.Video,
        Duration = 5,
        Priority = 2
    }

};
```

Estas es la lista donde quiero cargar el item que creo en la lista anterior.

```
var seqs = new System.Collections.Generic.List<MSequence>
{
    new MSequence()
    {
        Name = "Seq1",
        Description = "Desc1",
        Comments = "Comments1",
        Id = 1,
        Items = 

    },
    new MSequence()
    {
        Name = "Seq5",
        Description = "Desc1",
        Comments = "Comments1",
        Id = 5
    },
    new MSequence()
    {
        Name = "Seq4",
        Description = "Desc1",
        Comments = "Comments1",
        Id = 4
    },
    new MSequence()
    {
        Name = "Seq3",
        Description = "Desc1",
        Comments = "Comments1",
        Id = 3
    },
    new MSequence()
    {
        Name = "Seq2",
        Description = "Desc1",
        Comments = "Comments1",
        Id = 2
    }
};
```

Comment: No entiendo porqué quieres toda la lista de `MItem` en cada uno de los elementos de `seqs`

Comment: Deberías hacer de una manera más clara la pregunta, de que lista a que lista quieres pasar tus elementos?, no poder toda la creación de todos los items, ya que ahí solo dejas en evidencia que sabes instanciar objetos.

Comment: Perdón, no deseo toda la lista, solo deseo un elemento de la lista, gracias por notarlo

Comment: Hola vickry, ¿te refieres a que la variable `item` la quieres insertar en la primer posición de la variable `seqs`?

Comment: Para estar claros , y perdonen estoy aprendiendo, me refiero a lo siguiente: si quiero utilizar el ítem con el Id 4 y nombre el triple,

Comment: Para estar claros , y perdonen estoy aprendiendo, me refiero a lo siguiente: si quiero utilizar el ítem con el Id 4 y nombre el triple, etc. Cómo lo agrego en la propiedad ítem, dentro de la variable seqs?

Answer (score 0):

Si ya tienes la lista definida y solo la quieres asignar a la que tienes declarada en tu clase MSequence, una forma de hacerlo es en el constructor de la clase:

```
public class MSequence
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Comments { get; set; }
    public MSquenceType MSType { get; set; }
    public List<MItem> Items { get; set; }

    public MSequence()
    {
        Items = item;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Si entiendo bien tu pregunta, debes cambiar la definición de la clase `MSequence`para no almacenar una lista,si no el `MItem` que quieres enlazar:

```
public class MSequence
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Comments { get; set; }
    public MSquenceType MSType { get; set; }
    public MItem Item { get; set; }

    public MSequence()
    {

    }
}
```

Luego cuando generas tu lista de `MSequence` puedes hacerlo de varias maneras. Si quieres buscar el `MItem` por nombre para meterlo, puedes hacer algo asi:

```
var seqs = new System.Collections.Generic.List<MSequence>
{
    new MSequence()
    {
        Name = "Seq1",
        Description = "Desc1",
        Comments = "Comments1",
        Id = 1,
        Item = item.Where(x=> x.Name == "1 año Gratis").FirstOrDefault()
    },...    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

como los elementos son de distinto tipo y quieres incluir un elemento de un tipo en una lista de otro tipo. Creo que para lograr eso en vez de crear una lista fuertemente tipada debieras de crear una lista genérica, es decir, sin incluir el tipo MSequence:

```
var seqs = new System.Collections.Generic.List();
```

Al no estar tipada puedes añadir los objetos que quieras. Lo único que para acceder a la lista tienes que preguntar qué tipo de objeto es cada elemento y hacer un cast. En el siguiente código investiga el primer elemento de la lista:

```
if (seqs[0].GetType() == typeof(MSequence))
{
   MSequence MS = (MSequence)seqs[0];
   // Ya podrías acceder a los miembros de MS
   // MS.Name 
   // MS.
}
else if (seqs[0].GetType() == typeof(MItem))
{
   MItem MI = (MItem)seqs[0];
   // Ya podrías acceder a los miembros de MI
   // MI.Duration 
   // MI.Priority
   // MI.
}
```